# Firebase support form not working

Tags: firebase

I am trying to send a support request to Firebase, but the form is not working.

Do any other have the same problem? 
How to contact Firebase?

From my console:

```
GET https://firebase.google.com/_static/b0fba24d51/js/script_foot_closure__nb.js 
(index):1168 GET https://firebase.google.com/_static/b0fba24d51/js/script_foot_closure__nb.js 404 ()
script_foot.js:288 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initSettings' of undefined
    at Object.devsite.devsite.Init (script_foot.js:288)
    at (index):1171
    at (index):1176
devsite.devsite.Init @ script_foot.js:288
(anonymous) @ (index):1171
(anonymous) @ (index):1176
(index):1154 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Widget' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1154)
    at i (jquery-bundle.js:40)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-bundle.js:40)
    at Function.ready (jquery-bundle.js:40)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-bundle.js:40)
```

Comment: Hi. Have you tried sending the request using different browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera)? Is this happening to all?

Comment: Yes I have tried different browser ang from my phone. Same problem.

Comment: I am curious if you could attach any screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: This is strange. I've linked your post in the [Firebase Slack Community](https://firebase-community.slack.com/messages/general/). Hopefully a Firebaser will see it there too.

Comment: Also, any steps. Firebase support page seems to be working for me.

Comment: Same with @gerardnimo, the [Firebase Support form](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) works for me.

Comment: Her is a picture from the support page.  (you can se that the status is missing) https://www.dropbox.com/s/1d94oxcpx4c3l5g/Firebase_missingStatus.png?dl=0

Comment: One more link with the error message. https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqted6gu8exou39/Firebas_missingStatus2.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Google not having the actual file script_foot_closure__nb.js available on their server. The "nb" ending is for Norwegian (Bokmal) locale. I had the same issue with another of Google sited (developer console add mobile application).

Try changing the default locale for your browser to e.g. English. Either do it temporarily, or use a different browser for it (for example Firefox if you normally would use Chrome).

Comment: I just found this nice little tool - a quick-language-switcher for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-language-switcher/pmjbhfmaphnpbehdanbjphdcniaelfie